# Wordpress Ajax returns data correctly for admin user, but returns the entire home page for non-admins

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

So as the topic above states, I've got a 2 field form that posts two variables via ajax to a php file that queries via WP_User_Query. The returned data is then displayed on the page. The entire process works perfectly while logged on as an admin. The problem occurs when logged in as a subscriber & run the same script. The result that is returned is the entire home page loaded into my "results" div. I've checked the console and it says "XHR Loaded (admin-ajax.php - 302 Moved Temporarily" as well as another that reads, "XHR Loaded (websitenamehere) - 301 Moved Permanently".

Any help would be greatly appreciated or even pointed in a proper direction for trouble shooting. Here are the first few lines of my php code for that portion of it as I feel that's where the problem might lie.

```
//Add Activity to Database (AJAX)
add_action("wp_ajax_county_search", "county_search");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_county_search", "my_must_login_county_search");

function nceda_county_search() { ...
```

Here is my enqueue of the js files & ajax localization...

```
//Enqueue Scripts
add_action( 'init', 'my_script_enqueuer' );
function my_script_enqueuer() {
   wp_register_script( "member_search_script", WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/member-search/js/member-search.js', array('jquery') );      
   wp_localize_script( 'member_search_script', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));  
   wp_enqueue_script( 'member_search_script' ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**admin_url**

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url

> The admin_url template tag retrieves the url to the admin area for the
>   current site with the appropriate protocol, 'https' if is_ssl() and
>   'http' otherwise. If scheme is 'http' or 'https', is_ssl() is
>   overridden.
>
> Parameters $path (string) (optional) Path relative to the admin url.
>   Default: None $scheme (string) (optional) The scheme to use. Default
>   is 'admin', which obeys force_ssl_admin() and is_ssl(). 'http' or
>   'https' can be passed to force those schemes. The function uses
>   get_site_url(), so allowed values include any accepted by that
>   function. Default: 'admin'

Look at schema parametr

> (string) (optional) Scheme to give the site url context. Currently
>   'http', 'https', 'login', 'login_post', 'admin' or 'relative'.

try to use 'http' or null

or better use [site_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url)

Comment: Figured it out. I had a function in my functions.php that would redirect wp-admin requests to the home page, so any time non-admins called ajax, the result would be the home page, thus I had my home page nested within my ajax results. Removed the function, installed a "prevent dashboard access" plugin & everything is functioning as desired.